# Remote Notification app issue with FPPopover

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using FPPopover in my project and i was successful in displaying the popup in one of my view controller uibutton.
I am using remote notification as well in my app. when i open the app through notification which i recieved and try to click the uibutton for popup, i was not able to get the popup. Can you please help me out?

By
Siva M

Comment: Since you did not post any code, we really can't help you. Post you code and other relevant information.

Comment: Hi.. i am using fppopover class from this link https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover

Comment: Post the code where you open the popover when you open your app via the notification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your UIButton didn't exist yet. Should be easy to debug, if you still have the code around.